# Why does angular 2 cli generate component create a shared folder with index.ts

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

When I generate a component with the angular 2 cli:

ng g component "test" it creates a folder:

```
test
 |__Shared
 |   |__Index.ts
 |__test.component.html
 |__test.component.css
 |__etc...
```

What is the Shared folder? I mean what am I assumed to share between a html and css file? Or between a test.component.ts and a test.component.css ?

That makes no sense to me to create for each component a shared folder.

Can anyone explain that to me please?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared folder is created to stay in line with the style guide set forth from [angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#04-07). In this case it seems that the CLI is anticipating that you might create components within components and so it creates the shared folder when a component is created.

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1142) is some more reading about someone who questioned why there was a shared folder.